# Observer.hasActiveObservers() is false when state is RESUMED?

Tags: android

I am trying to test some `LiveData` in a `Viewmodel`

I have mocked both `LifecycleOwner` and `LifecycleRegistry`

My test method below:

```
@Test
public void testLifecycle(){
    assertThat(viewModel.user().hasObservers(), is(false));

    Observer<FirebaseUser> firebaseUserObserver = (Observer<FirebaseUser>)mock(Observer.class);
    viewModel.user().observe(lifecycleOwner, firebaseUserObserver);

    assertThat(viewModel.user().hasObservers(), is(true));

    lifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);    
    assertThat(viewModel.user().hasActiveObservers(),is(true));    //assertion failure

    lifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED);
    assertThat(viewModel.user().hasActiveObservers(), is(false));
}
```

When I run this method I get a assertion failure at:

```
assertThat(viewModel.user().hasActiveObservers(),is(true));
```

I don't understand why this fails. `hasActiveObservers()` should return `true` if `LiveData` has at least one observer whose lifecycle is `Lifecycle.State.STARTED` or `Lifecycle.State.RESUMED` state (this means state is active).

Have I missed something here?

Comment: If you've mocked the `LifecycleRegistry`, then `setCurrentState()` doesn't call into the actual implemention. Why are you mocking `LifecycleRegistry` at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Makes sense, you are correct. Should I only mock the LifecycleOwner and create lifecycleregistry as usual? Is that what you should do to test Viewmodel Livedata?

Comment: If you want the real behavior of `LifecycleRegistry`, then you should create a real `LifecycleRegistry` object.

Comment: Okay, I see.  Testing runs as it should, thanks for the help. If you want, you could reply the first comment as an aswer so I can accept for any future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've mocked the `LifecycleRegistry`, then `setCurrentState()` doesn't call into the actual implementation. If you want the real behavior of `LifecycleRegistry` (i.e., actually changing the state to an active state), then you should create a real `LifecycleRegistry` object.

Comment: Please look into this question I tried to solve it but could not solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513672/errorunable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebugandroidtest-compileclasspath @ianhanniballake